# ArrayAdapter and ViewGroup.GetChildAt not working properly

Tags: android

I have a Listview with a custom layout for each row. The custom layout consists of a LinearLayout, having two other LinearLayouts as children (L1 and L2). L1 contains the basic information of the row while L2 contains visual signals which provide relevant information to the user. The end result looks like this:

[image: ListView Layout]

The colourful squares are simple TextViews that have a drawable object set as backgroud. The L2 xml looks like this:

```
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/hasReceipt"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/blank" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/warehouseMonitor"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/blank" />


    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swapDeliver"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/blank" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swapReturn"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/blank" />
```

The condition for "lighting up" a signal is checked in the overriden `getView` function of the ArrayAdapter. The appropriate View is cast from the ViewGroup hierarchy as shown in the example below:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ViewGroup mainViewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
    ViewGroup visualSignalsGroup = (ViewGroup) mainViewGroup.getChildAt(1); // L2

    TextView tvOrder = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(0);
    TextView tvPayment = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(1);
    TextView tvReceipt = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(3);
    TextView tvWarehouseMonitor = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(4);
    TextView tvSwapDeliver = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(5);
    TextView tvSwapReturn = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(6);

    if (checkCondition(position)){
        tvReceipt.setBackgroundDrawable(hasReceipt);
    } else {
        tvReceipt.setBackgroundDrawable(blank);
    }

}
```

If I want to add more visual signals, I add more TextViews in L2 and calling `getChildAt` with the appropriate index. Everything works well up to index 5. The light blue signal on the right in the picture, is index 6. The condition for lighting it up is true only for the first row. While debbuging, the breakpoint is hit only for the first row. As you can see, it is visible in other rows as well and I really cannot explain this behaviour as the default state is "blank" and the breakpoint is only hit once.

I paste below the full code of the array adapter:

```
public class StableArrayAdapter extends DArrayAdapter {


HashMap<String, Customers.Customer> mcusMap = new HashMap<String, Customers.Customer>();
Context context = getContext();

static Customers customers;
public static ArrayList<String> customerNames;


Drawable order = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.order);
Drawable paymentCompleted = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.payment_completed);
Drawable blank = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blank);
Drawable hasReceipt = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.has_receipt);
Drawable warehouseMonitor = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.warehouse_monitor);
Drawable swapDeliver = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.swap_deliver);
Drawable swapReturn = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.swap_return);


public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int listViewLayout, int textViewID, ArrayList<String> customerNames) {
    super(context, listViewLayout, textViewID, customerNames);
    customers = Customers.getCustomers(context);
    StableArrayAdapter.customerNames = customers.customerNames;
    int i = 0;
    for (Customers.Customer customer : customers.list.values()) {
        mIdMap.put(customer.name, i);
        mcusMap.put(customer.name, customer);
        i++;
    }

}


private static ArrayList<String> init() {
    ArrayList<String> customerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Object[] customerArray = customers.list.values().toArray();
    for (Object customer : customerArray) {
        customerNames.add(((Customers.Customer) customer).name);
    }
    StableArrayAdapter.customerNames = customerNames;
    return customerNames;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ViewGroup mainVewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
    ViewGroup vgRowTextViewGroup = (ViewGroup) mainVewGroup.getChildAt(0);
    ViewGroup visualSignalsGroup = (ViewGroup) mainVewGroup.getChildAt(1);

    TextView rowText = (TextView) vgRowTextViewGroup.getChildAt(0);


    TextView tvOrder = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(0);
    TextView tvPayment = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(1);
    TextView tvReceipt = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(3);
    TextView tvWarehouseMonitor = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(4);
    TextView tvSwapDeliver = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(5);
    TextView tvSwapReturn = (TextView) visualSignalsGroup.getChildAt(6);

    Customers.Customer customer = mcusMap.get(customerNames.get((position)));

    if (customer.longitude == 0 || customer.latitude == 0) {
        rowText.setBackgroundColor(0xfffface4);
    } else {
        rowText.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
    }

    if (customer.hasOrders) tvOrder.setBackgroundDrawable(order);
    else tvOrder.setBackgroundDrawable((blank));


    if (Routing.Current != null && Routing.Current.trdrLines.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(mcusMap.get(customerNames.get(position)).trdr))) {
        RoutingTrdrLine line = Routing.Current.trdrLines.get(Integer.parseInt(mcusMap.get(customerNames.get(position)).trdr));
        if (line.paymentStatus > 0) {
            tvPayment.setBackgroundDrawable(paymentCompleted);
        } else {
            tvPayment.setBackgroundDrawable(blank);
        }

        if (line.receipt > 0 && line.receiptPayment == 0) {
            tvReceipt.setBackgroundDrawable(hasReceipt);
        } else {
            tvReceipt.setBackgroundDrawable(blank);
        }

        if (line.warehouseMonitorObject != null && line.warehouseMonitorObject.WarehouseMonitorStatus == 0) {
            tvWarehouseMonitor.setBackgroundDrawable(warehouseMonitor);
        } else {
            tvWarehouseMonitor.setBackgroundDrawable(blank);
        }

        if (line.swapDeliverItems != null) {
            Boolean delivered = false;
            for (SwapDeliverItem item :
                    line.swapDeliverItems) {
                if (item.Delivered == 1) {
                    delivered = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!delivered) {
                tvSwapDeliver.setBackgroundDrawable(swapDeliver);
            } else {
                tvSwapDeliver.setBackgroundDrawable(blank);
            }
        }

        if (line.swapReturnItems != null) {
            Boolean returned = false;
            for (SwapReturnItem item :
                    line.swapReturnItems) {
                if (item.Returned == 1) {
                    returned = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!returned) {
                tvSwapReturn.setBackgroundDrawable(swapReturn);
            } else {
                tvSwapReturn.setBackgroundDrawable(blank);
            }
        }

    } else {
        tvPayment.setBackgroundDrawable(blank);
    }

    //todo change view depending on


    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Your post lacks enough information to investigate the problem.  In particular, it's hard to help with code issues without seeing the relevant parts of the code—a description of the code ("If I want to add more visual signals, I add more TextViews in L2 and calling getChildAt with the appropriate index.") is usually not enough.  The issue is almost certainly handling recycling incorrectly, but it's impossible to tell without that part of the code.

Comment: Dear @RyanM, this is the only part of the code. I believe the checkCondition() function is irrelevant that is why I did not include it. When I want to add more visual signals, I copy/paste one of the TextView nodes and I change its id. I then cast this new TextView in code, by incrementing the index of getChiltAt. I am not aware what you mean by "recycling".

Comment: If this is a recycling issue, why the incosistencies are not propagated in other elements of the same row?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have the code for all the elements.  The code in the question only changes `tvReceipt`.

Comment: @RyanM I edited the question and pasted the full code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These `if` statements do not have an `else` case that resets the state of what they set:

```java
if (line.swapDeliverItems != null) {
```

```java
if (line.swapReturnItems != null) {
```

The state of the `TextView`s is only reset if the field is non-null - it should always be reset.

Comment: This is legacy code. This else statement never runs. The if condition is always true. Nevertheless I added all the missing statements but still no lack. Every signal is reset from the internal ifs in the original code.

Comment: Edited with a different theory.

Comment: Golden!! Thanks!!